# Google App Engine - Start / Stop Flex instance from Python API

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Do know if it's possible to Stop & Start a version of one Flex Google App Version directly from apps ?

#### Not by gcloud client ...

Obviously it's working by the gcloud command : `gcloud app versions stop/start <version>`

#### ... like in the Google Web Interface ...

I take a look at the Google Web service where the button start/stop is working well. The request is passed to the url :

```
https://console.cloud.google.com/m/operations?operationType=cloud-console.appengine.stopStartVersions&pid=<PROJECT-NAME>&hl=fr
```

With this data :

```
 {"pid":"<PROJECT-NAME>","serviceId":"<SERVICE-ID>","versionId":"<VERSION-ID>","serving":true,"descriptionLocalizationKey":"gaeStopStartVersions","descriptionLocalizationArgs":{"serving":"true","versionId":"<VERSION-ID>"}}
```

#### ... but by Python API

I try to follow the documentation about patching version. Whith this code or example :

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
appengine = discovery.build('appengine', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
apps = appengine.apps()
apps.services().versions().patch(appsId='<ID-APP>',servicesId='<ID-SERVICE>',versionsId="<ID-VERSION>",body = {'servingStatus': 'STOPPED'},updateMask='servingStatus').execute()
```

This is working. The version stopping and instances shutting down. But when I do the same with `SERVING` the version turn on but instances are not created.

Did someone already succed to do that correctly ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: It is possible and you are doing it in the correct way, proof of that is that you are able to change the `servingStatus` to `STOPPED`, are you getting any error responses on that?

Comment: Hi Rafael, thanks for your answer. No, there is no error responses. In fact, the version is really running after patch with 'RUNNING'. I can see that on the web interface. But no instance is created so I get error when I want to use the app.

Comment: This is an odd behavior indeed, I would advise you to open a Bug Report in [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187191&template=0) for their engineering team to check this, as this could be a bug in the App Engine API.